# audio player stutters when slider updates every second

Tags: ios, swift, slider, avaudioplayer, tvos

I am using [TvOSSlider](https://github.com/zattoo/TvOSSlider.git) in my tv app to create a seek-bar and play audio track with AVAudioPlayer. My problem is that it is stuttering every time i update the seekbar/slider through code. So currently it is set to stutter every 1.0seconds. UISlider is unavailable in tvOS that is why i am using this different library.

```
func playAudio(url: URL, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    stopAudio()
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        audioPlayer?.delegate = self
        audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer?.play()
        isPaused = false
        // Start the playback timer to update the seek bar
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            // This is where timer is set and update Slider method is called. I tried to set it from 0.1 sec to 5 sec
            playbackTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        completion?()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error initializing AVAudioPlayer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion?()
    }
}
// Update the slider value based on the current playback time
@objc func updateSlider() {  // This function gets called above
    guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
    slider?.setValue(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime / audioPlayer.duration), animated: true) // This line causes the stuttering
}
```

I have tried background DispatchQueue but it crashes the app saying slider.setvalue must be called from main thread as it updates ui. I also tried playing audio in the background thread but that was a doomed idea to begin with. Following is my audio manager code

```
import AVFAudio
import TvOSSlider

class AudioManager {
    static let shared = AudioManager()
    
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    var playbackTimer: Timer?
    private var isPaused = false
    var slider: TvOSSlider? // Add a reference to the slider
    
    private init() { }
    
    func playAudio(url: URL, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        stopAudio()
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer?.play()
            isPaused = false
            // Start the playback timer to update the seek bar
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                playbackTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }
            completion?()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error initializing AVAudioPlayer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion?()
        }
    }
    
    func togglePlayPause() {
        guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else {
            return
        }
        
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.pause()
            playbackTimer?.invalidate()
            playbackTimer = nil
            isPaused = true
        } else {
            audioPlayer.play()
            playbackTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isPaused = false
        }
    }

    func stopAudio() {
        audioPlayer?.stop()
        audioPlayer = nil
        isPaused = false
        
        playbackTimer?.invalidate()
        playbackTimer = nil
    }
    
    // MARK: - Slider methods
    
    // Update the slider value based on the current playback time
    @objc func updateSlider() {
        guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
        slider?.setValue(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime / audioPlayer.duration), animated: true)
    }
    
    // Seek to the desired position in the audio
    @objc func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: TvOSSlider) {
        guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
        let targetTime = TimeInterval(sender.value) * audioPlayer.duration
        audioPlayer.currentTime = targetTime
    }
    
}
```

And here is my use of this in my view controller

```
import TvOSSlider

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
...

    @IBOutlet weak var tvosSlider: TvOSSlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupView()
        playSongFromUrl()
        getData()
        
    }

    func setupView(){
        
//        // Set the AudioManager's slider property
        AudioManager.shared.slider = tvosSlider
        AudioManager.shared.slider?.addTarget(AudioManager.shared, action: #selector(AudioManager.sliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        ...
    }

    func play(url: URL) {
        AudioManager.shared.playAudio(url: url){
            self.stopLoader()
        }
    }
...
}
```

Now i am unable to find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up editing in the library [TvOSSlider](https://github.com/zattoo/TvOSSlider)'s code to solve the stuttering problem.

This method is used to update the slider `slider?.setValue(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime / audioPlayer.duration), animated: true)` I right click on `setValue` method and select `Jump to definition` there I click unlock on making changes to the code and made following changes.

```
/// A control used to select a single value from a continuous range of values.
public final class TvOSSlider: UIControl {
...

    public func setValue(_ value: Float, animated: Bool) {
        self.value = value
//        stopDeceleratingTimer() \\ I commented this line to prevent stuttering.
        
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
                self.setNeedsLayout()
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in above method the only thing I changed was i commented `stopDeceleratingTimer()`.
Now I do not have a complete grasp of what it does. However, this solved my problem without creating a new one. So cheers.

Comment: I used the same pod for the slider and encountered an issue: when I moved the slider, the video would always start from the beginning. With this code, my issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AudioManager {
// From 
// playbackTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
// To this will give smoother experience (1.0 to 0.1)
playbackTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: The problem was not the visual smoothness but the audio smoothness disturbed by the visual updates. It is now solved as the issue was in the library. However thanks for your answer as well.